# Stop mp3 playing on another button click and exiting page

Tags: android, mp3, ondestroy

I have tried all the examples that I can find on this site but I can't seem to get it to work.
I need it so that if a mp3 file is started by pressing a button, if another button is pressed then the previous mp3 stops and the new one starts.

I also need it to stop when navigating away from the page.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class buttontofirstaidaed extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        private MediaPlayer mp1;
        private MediaPlayer mp2;
        private MediaPlayer mp3;
        private MediaPlayer mp4;
        private MediaPlayer mp5;
        private MediaPlayer mp6;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstaidaed);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Button buttonaed1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_aed1);
        Button buttonaed2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_aed2);
        Button buttonaed3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_aed3);
        Button buttonaed4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_aed4);
        Button buttonaed5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_aed5);
        Button buttonaed6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_aed6);

        buttonaed1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonaed2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonaed3.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonaed4.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonaed5.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonaed6.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int resId1;
        int resId2;
        int resId3;
        int resId4;
        int resId5;
        int resId6;

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button_aed1:
            resId1 = R.raw.aed1;
            if(mp1!=null) { mp1.release(); } mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId1); mp1.start();
            break;

        case R.id.button_aed2:
            resId2 = R.raw.aed2;
            if(mp2!=null) { mp2.release(); } mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId2); mp2.start();
            break;

        case R.id.button_aed3:
            resId3 = R.raw.aed3;
            if(mp3!=null) { mp3.release(); } mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId3); mp3.start();
            break;

        case R.id.button_aed4:
            resId4 = R.raw.aed4;
            if(mp4!=null) { mp4.release(); } mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId4); mp4.start();
            break;

        case R.id.button_aed5:
            resId5 = R.raw.aed5;
            if(mp5!=null) { mp5.release(); } mp5 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId5); mp5.start();
            break;

        case R.id.button_aed6:
            resId6 = R.raw.aed6;
            if(mp6!=null) { mp6.release(); } mp6 = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId6); mp6.start();
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: you can have a single MediaPlayer (e.g. singleton pattern) for all stuff

Comment: Hi Koutuk. I have a xml page called firstaidaed. The page has six buttons which all play a different sound that a defibrilltor makes. When I click on one button the mp3 starts to play, but if I click on another button the first sound keeps playing too as well as the second sound. The sounds also keep playing if I navigate away from the page.

Comment: Hi sinpin, I'm not really sure what you mean, I have taken this code from other pages on this website and altered the mp3 file names to suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use then the same MediaPlayer for all of your sounds.

Then in every button click stop it and initialize again with the corresponding media.

Have a look to the MediaPlayer cycle of live. It looks crazy at first time xD

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

try with something like this

```
private MediaPlayer genericMediaPlayer = null;
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(genericMediaPlayer == null) {
       genericMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this);    
    } else {
       genericMediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    FileDescriptor audio = null; 

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.button_aed1:
        audio = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.audio1).getFileDescriptor();
        break;

    case R.id.button_aed2:
        audio =getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.audio3).getFileDescriptor();
        break;

    case R.id.button_aed3:
        audio = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.audio3).getFileDescriptor();
        break;

    case R.id.button_aed4:
        audio = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.audio4).getFileDescriptor();
        break;

    case R.id.button_aed5:
        audio = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.audio5).getFileDescriptor();
        break;

    case R.id.button_aed6:
        audio = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.audio6).getFileDescriptor();
        break;

    }
     if(audio != null){
        genericMediaPlayer.setDataSource(audio);
        genericMediaPlayer.prepare();
        genericMediaPlayer.start();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thankyou for your replies guys. When I enter that code genericMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this); The create is underlined as an error. If I use the suggested fixes that eclipse brings up the page opens but it is blank.

Comment: I didn't check it sorry. Just change MediaPlayer.create(this) by new MediaPlayer();

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't work either I'm afraid. I need to add a bracket at the bottom. When I add the brackets it underlines genericMediaPlayer.setDataSource(audio);
genericMediaPlayer.prepare(); If I add the catchblocks then the sounds don't play at all. I have also had to input the @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.firstaidaed); to get the page to open. Really puzzled.

Comment: I have managed to get this working using other code but there was a seperate issue. \\the link to that problem is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424518/code-works-on-nexus-one-galaxys2-but-not-galaxy-s4

Answer (score 0):

All fixed now, the link to the other issue has solved the problem. Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use same media player and on start of each click use:

```
if (player!=null) {
    player.stop();
}
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.recording);
start();
```